# Make node for each unique user and update the value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I started working with Firebase, and I have a simple app that stores a random integer every few seconds to the database. But, everytime the random number is generated, it is replaced in the same node on the Firebase database (So I always have 1 node instead of 2 for each device the app is currently installed on).
I want that for each device the app is installed, the random number will be replaced for the same user (So each user has his own node with constantly changing random number)

This is the simple code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue(randomInteger);
```

How to make a node for each unique user, where the number that's randomly generated will replace the old one?

Comment: is there a .push() function instead of .setValue() ? If so, use .push and firebase will generate automatically a UID node for your new intergers

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake yes this would in fact work, but as the question from OP suggests, he would need to constantly update the value of that number. So this might make so many nodes with unique pushed `uid`'s that may pose a problem.

Comment: Hey @TTnote, do mark the answer as correct and vote it up, if it is useful, this helps people with similar question on Stack Overflow, and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can control each user without membership transactions.

```
Context context = this;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences preferences;
String userKey;

preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
editor = preferences.edit();

userKey = preferences.getString("userKey", null);

if (userKey == null) {
        DatabaseReference dbNewRef = db.getReference("message");
        userKey = dbNewRef.push().getKey();
        editor.putString("userKey", userKey);
        editor.apply();
    }

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message/userKey");
myRef.setValue(randomInteger);
```

Comment: I would push there : myRef.push(randomInteger) so it won't overrite the value as OP asked

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to have something that changes for every user (or every device, as you stated in the question), I would suggest to make your database according to that.

What I mean by it is that you can have separate node for each of your user with his own unique name or `uid` that can have a child node with your random integer value.

Your database structure would look something like this:

```json
FirebaseUniqueIden
|
|
 --- uid1
| |
|  -- randomValue
| |
|
| 
 --- uid2
 |
  -- randomeValue
 |
```

So this would ensure your every user to have his own space which can be constantly updated with his own unique random number.

Now the question arises how would you get a structure like this. The answer is very simple, you can get the `uid` of every user using `FirebaseAuth.getUid()`. This `uid` is unique for every user and is decided when you log in the user.

So to set up this in your database, you can just use a code like this:

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

ref.child(mAuth.getUid()).child("randomValue").setValue(random);

// mAuth is FirebaseAuth variable
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are pointing to the same node every time you are saving that randomInteger, that's why it's replace over and over.

One way to be able to achieve what you are trying to do is to capture the current time in milli seconds and pass it to the reference node:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.child(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
myRef.setValue(randomInteger);
```

This way you will have a "milli seconds time" node under "message" node for each time you set that randomInteger.